# How do I see which varibles were chosen from SelectK

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am using scikit learn's SelectK on my classification problem. How can I see which variables were chosen by SelectK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest), you should use: [`get_support()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.get_support).

Use `get_support(indices=True)` to get an array of integers, rather than a boolean mask.